# Who authored "Legends of the Land of Israel"?

Tags: authorship

In a question regarding the [Kosel](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29649/what-is-the-source-that-the-western-wall-was-built-by-the-poor) there is a link to an Aish article. In the article it mentions in the name of a book "Legends of the Land of Israel" that the Kosel HaMaaravi was built by the poor.

> The building of the Western Wall fell to the poor, and they worked
>   hard to construct it, as they could not afford to hire laborers to do
>   their work for them. When the enemy destroyed the Temple, the angels
>   descended from on high and – spreading their wings over the Wall –
>   said: "This Wall, the work of the poor, shall never be destroyed."
>   (from "Legends of the Land of Israel")

Who authored this book? I have been unable to find such a title.

Comment: Did you try emailing Aish?

Comment: @DoubleAA: Awaiting their reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zev Vilnay: Legends of Palestine (1922), later renamed to Legends of the Land of Israel.

See here, page 67:

http://books.google.com/books?id=VkA6-0-aDdIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA67#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Is this a reliable book?

Comment: @GershonGold if this still interests you, Vilnay was considered an important historian. He even won the Israel Prize. [Here's](https://www.jstor.org/stable/23807639?refreqid=excelsior%3A2b27ad5f47303456775c8bd8697dfd65&seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) a review of his book. Bear in mind that this a collection of legends, some from reputable sources and some not. In his book Legends of Jerusalem, he attributes this particular story to "I heard this from a Jewish youth in the Old City, Jerusalem, 1922". https://archive.org/details/VILNAYLegendsOfJerusalem/page/n345/mode/2up?q=poor